# Broken undo in editor. Lost content many times

Tags: bug

I was typing a message and on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> giant piece disappeared and I wasn't able to recover it. It happened to me a few times already. Something funky going on with text edit box on stackoverflow!

It definetely looks broken and fully reproducible when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> inside a block of code. Second <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> erases it all!

Comment: Looks similar but in my case when I edit a block of code ctrl+z undoes last minor edit, second ctrl-z removes entire block of code even if it's 20 lines written over 5-10 minutes.

Comment: The bottom line is: the undo/redo is broken, and causes data loss, and it has been this way for years, and it seems that everyone at SO has more important things to do than fix this.

Comment: its your browser doing it, not the editor itself.

Comment: @Daniel Nope, it's the SO editor. It overrides default browser behavior, and replaces it with this badly functioning undo-redo. See the dupe for more info